# Selectively build packages with dpkg-buildpackage

Tags: debian, compiling, package-management

When you download source codes with `apt-get source` command, it usually consists of multiple packages, e.g the `eglibc` source package contains glibc-doc, libc-bin, etc.

Now with `dpkg-buildpackage` command it builds all packages at once.

So, can I selectively build the package I want? It can be too slow building them all?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @FaheemMitha added an example

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to know whether you need to build all the binary packages corresponding to a source package. Why don't you want to build them all? If you want we can do this in chat. The main chat room. I'm on there. If you want to, ping me there.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's slow

Comment: Well, it depends on the package. If there is a separate build process for different binary packages, then you can remove the build processes you don't want. However, in general, this is not the case. I.e. the different binary packages are the outcome of one build process.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the package. If there is a separate build process for different binary packages, then you can remove the build processes you don't want. However, in general, this is not the case. I.e. the different binary packages are the outcome of a single build process.

The build is defined in the `debian/rules` file. You should look there to see how the package is built.

If you are concerned about the build speed, it may be possible to parallelize the build. Note that `debian/rules` is just a Make file, and is called by `make -f debian/rules`.

One other thing that can speed things up is removing the test step, which many packages support ([docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options)):

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage
```

Comment: `dpkg-buildpackage` doesn't accept package name as argument

Comment: @MichałF Agreed. Better now?

Answer (score -1):

In order to build a package from sources on debian you can use folowing steps:

```
apt-get build-dep stellarium
apt-get source -b stellarium
```

or step by step with dpkg-buildpackage

```
apt-get build-dep stellarium
apt-get source stellarium
cd stellarium*/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -rfakeroot
```